# IDEA plugin development:how to execute some custom actions while editing live templates?

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, live-templates

I am developing a plugin to enhance the live template function of IDEA.

Consider the editing box when refactoring the name of a variable:

[image: example image]

While typing code in such a replacement box, I want to get the text after finising inputting and do something, or get the variable name (like `$value$` in the template text) of this replacement box.
Does anyone know how to do it?